# make you remember or make you remembered

Tags: grammar

Please, someone help me to learn which one is correct...

He will make you ***remember*** or He will make you ***remembered***.

Answer (score 3):

He will make you **remember**; He will make you **remembered**, both are correct depending on the [context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_%28language_use%29):

*He will make you remember* relates to him helping **your memory**; " as he strives to make Devyn remember the good times, will his passion and heart be enough to regain her trust?"-[Make You Remember](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451465342).

*He will make you remembered* relates to making **others remember you**; "  [Anne Frank Remembered](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001977JM) is an Oscar-winning account of the real girl behind the famous diary, including vintage newsreels, photographs, a rare home movie and emotional interviews with Anne's family, friends and protector Miep Gies."

Comment: Good point.  For instance, a good publicity agent can make a band famous, well-known, remembered.

Answer (score 2):

He makes you remember. He made you remember. He will make you remember. He has made you remember. He had made you remember.

The tense does not matter. Use the root verb. That is,  infinitive, but without "to".